# Collection count incorrect in Meteor + Angular

Tags: angularjs, meteor, collections, count, subscribe

I am using Meteor + AngularJS2. The count of one of my collections often changes, confusing.

Key code fragments:

1.route.js

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');
        $stateProvider
            .state('dnm', {
                url: '/dnm',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'client/templates/devmch.html',
                resolve: {
                    devMchs: function() {
                        subs.subscribe('Devices');
                        subs.subscribe('Machines');
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('dnm.devs', {
                url: '/devs',
                templateUrl: 'client/templates/devices.html',
                controller: 'DevicesCtrl'
            }
        }
        ...
```

2.devices.controller.js

```
import { Devices } from '../../../lib/collections';

angular.module('devices')
    .controller('DevicesCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.helpers ({
            count: function () {
                return Devices.find().count();
            },
            devices: function (){
                return Devices.find();
            }
        });
    }]);
```

3.devices.html

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        Total Devices(Method 1): {{ count }}<br />
        Total Devices(Method 2): {{ devices.count() }}
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="device in devices">
                {{ device.name }}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

As you can see, "Devices" is subscribed by its parent state "dnm", using the resolve function. After running, the correct devices are list up in the devices html page (here I have 4 devices). but the device count, no matter using method 1 or 2, it was often an incorrect value ( 1 or 2 or 3).

If I refresh the page, I can get a correct count value. but the first time ng.

Comment: Please make sure you do not confuse AngularJS with Angular2

Comment: I am not familiar w/ Angular.  Does `$scope.helpers` get run reactively?  From what you are saying is happening, it seems like it isn't.  I would put a console.log right before `return Devices.find().count();` to see if it's getting called as the collection changes.  I have a feeling you will only see it called one time. If that's the case, the reason the count is off when you first load the page is because it fires before the subscription has pulled all the data down, so your count is 0 or maybe some partial, but the second time the subscription is already done so the count is accurate.

Comment: @ghybs Thanks for your advice. From angularjs.org's homepage, I understand AngularJS has two versions: AngularJS 1 and Angular 2. "Angular JS2" is invented by myself and does not exist. But I guess you know what I mean is Angular 2.

Comment: @vdonkey Angular2 has no `$scope`

Comment: @ghybs Omg, I believed I was using Angular2 all the time! I didn't know angular before I started following the "WhatsApp2" sample project tutorial from angular-meteor.com, and then just learned about what appeared in the source e.g. controller or directive. But the angular-meteor said the tutorial is based on angular2...

Comment: @CodeChimp I tried adding console.log before return, but this time I got the correct count value...strange.. I have to test a bit more then report. many thanks

Comment: Take out the console.log and see if it still works. If not, I am not sure what to say as that doesn't make any logical sense given my limited understanding of how reactivity works in Meteor. If it does still work, perhaps there was an issue where the code wasn't being updated as you though?

Comment: @CodeChimp Finally I got this problem solved. the reason is I used i18n which I didn't notice, even not mentioned in my question. Like this: <span i18n="u-hv-devs" cnt="{{ devices.count() }}">. "u-hv-devs" is defined: "You have %cnt devices in total". so, when cnt changed the span's text didn't. So I asked a wrong question, I apologize and will delete the question later.

Comment: No worries.  I am glad you found it.